# Sorting items into shipping packages, Models with belongs_to relationship in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I'm trying to sort variations into boxes to calculate shipping via the USPS API. Each box can contain a specific amount of variations before it needs to be places in a new box. Each variation belongs to a ShippingBox

This seems like a very specific question for which I'm sure there's a vague (but good) answer floating around on the internet. I'm unsure of what to search for to help me on my way.

#### Variation

```
class Variation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shipping_box
end
```

#### ShippingBox

```
class ShippingBox < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :weight, :box_length, :box_height, :box_depth, :maximum_quantity
end
```

This is some pretty worthless code right now, but I feel like I'm on the right track

```
packages = o.variations.reduce([]) do |boxes, item|
    this_box_type = item.shipping_type
    boxes << [this_box_type.name] if boxes.empty?

    boxes.each_with_index do |box, index|
        if boxes[index].length < this_box_type.maximum_quantity
            boxes[index] << item
        end
    end
end
```

results

```
=> [["25x6x6", #<Variation id: 20, cart_id: 4, order_id: nil, quantity: 2, created_at: "2013-11-26 17:49:53", updated_at: "2013-11-26 17:50:08">]]
```

I find myself stuck not being able to set 2-dimensional arrays, or knowing how to use a variable as a hash key and set the value. I think, ideally the result would be something like:

```
[["25x6x6", [#<Variation id: 20, cart_id: 4, order_id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: "2013-11-26 17:49:53", updated_at: "2013-11-26 17:50:08">, #<Variation id: 20, cart_id: 4, order_id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: "2013-11-26 17:49:53", updated_at: "2013-11-26 17:50:08">]], ["30x5x5", [#<Variation id: 21, cart_id: 4, order_id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: "2013-11-26 17:49:53", updated_at: "2013-11-26 17:50:08">]]]
```

#### order.shipping_types_in_order

```
[{:shipping_id=>4}, {:shipping_id=>2}]
```

#### order.flat_packing_list

```
[#<Variation id: 20, cart_id: 4, order_id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: "2013-11-26 17:49:53", updated_at: "2013-11-28 14:33:35">, #<Variation id: 24, cart_id: 4, order_id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: "2013-11-28 14:00:59", updated_at: "2013-11-28 14:00:59">, #<Variation id: 25, cart_id: 4, order_id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: "2013-11-28 14:33:32", updated_at: "2013-11-28 14:33:32">]
```

### Update 1

```
packages = order.shipping_types_in_order.reduce([]) do |items, boxes|
    temp = []
    puts boxes[:shipping_id]
    order.flat_packing_list.reduce([]) do |x, item|
        if boxes[:shipping_id] == [item.shipping_type.id]
            temp << item
        end
    end
    boxes[:shipping_id] << temp
end
```

shipping_types_in_order is an array of all unique shipping boxes available for that order. Looping through my order's available shipping boxes and checking the items against that seems to be a much simpler logic, but I'm still at a loss.

### Update 2

```
items = Array.new
packages = order.shipping_types_in_order.reduce([]) do |x, box|
    pack_list = { box: box[:shipping_id], packages: [] }
    total = order.flat_packing_list.reduce([]) do |y, item|
        puts "shipping_id: #{item.variation.shipping_type.id}"
        if box[:shipping_id] == item.variation.shipping_type.id
            pack_list[:packages] << item
        end
    end
    items << pack_list
end
```

I think this is really quite close now

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be

```
boxes[index] << [item]
```